# Customize radio button in windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have two radio button.I want to add a custom image for instead of a default style.

Example: I want to show image 1 for radio button which is selected and image 2 for all other radio button which are not selected.

The current radio button code, I have tried.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rbCashFee" Content="Send with Cash out fee" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsChecked="True" Height="59" Foreground="Black"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="8,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform/>
                        </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton x:Name="rbNCashFee" Content="Send without Cash out fee" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="59" Foreground="Black" Margin="8,0">
                        <RadioButton.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#000"/>
                        </RadioButton.BorderBrush>
                        <RadioButton.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#fff"/>
                        </RadioButton.Background>                        
</RadioButton>
```

Can some one kindly help me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your must change controls' templates.Read this article to understand how to do it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.template

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to it in xaml I suggest you do it in the .cs file of that page by using SelectionChanged events and set the properties for your radiobutton dynamically in the .cs file.